# Oracle SQL - Trying to get opponent's name

Tags: sql, oracle

So i have two tables, user and board

```
create table user (
usernum int,
usernam varchar(100),
primary key (usernum)
);

create table board (
boardnum int, 
tournum int, 
rotation int, 
x_player int,  
o_player int, 
x_points number, 
o_points number, 
foreign key(x_player) references user,
foreign key(o_player) references user);
```

For the sake of reference, lets say the user Joe has the ID 1 and assume we have 9 other players, and have the following boards

```
insert into board values(1,1,1,1,2,0,1);
insert into board values(2,1,1,1,3,0.5,0.5);
insert into board values(3,1,1,1,4,1,0);
insert into board values(4,1,1,1,5,0,1);


insert into board values(5,1,2,6,1,0,1);
insert into board values(6,1,2,7,1,1,0);
insert into board values(7,1,2,8,1,1,0);
insert into board values(8,1,2,9,1,0.5,0.5);
```

What would be my query to figure out the names of all the opponents who have faced Joe? I am currently stuck at

```
SELECT usernam FROM user INNER JOIN board ON usernum = x_player AND usernum    = o_player.
```

I'm a SQL newbie so help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the definition of the PAIRING table?

Comment: @BobC sorry, its board not pairing :p

Comment: This doesn't make sense - you need to provide the necessary data for the `user` table. One can offer you a query that gives the `number` of each player who has faced Joe; but your `user` table doesn't have the test data for players with numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but see if this works:

```sql
SELECT x.usernam,
       o.usernam
FROM board b
JOIN USER x ON b.x_player = x.usernum
JOIN USER o ON b.o_player = o.usernum

/* Then if you want just Joe, you add the WHERE clause below */

WHERE x.usernam = 'Joe'
  OR o.usernam = 'Joe'
```

Comment: Hey bob, thanks for the reply. I need the name of Joe's opponents, not Joe's. And just ran the code, and it didn't work.

Comment: OK, Just tested it and fixed the error. BTW, "user" is a reserved word in Oracle, so I changed the user table to be something else.

Comment: Now as you are probably discovering, there are multiple solutions to your problem as stated. So you might want to give an example of the desired output :)

Comment: Basically my output should be: Natasha /n Tanya, so, the names of the players that faced Joe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136202/discussion-between-spartan-117-and-bobc).

Answer (score 1):

The following returns one row per user who has faced Joe:

```
select distinct (case when x.usernam = 'Joe'
                      then o.usernam else x.usernam
                 end) as other_usernam
from board b join
     user x
     on b.x_player = x.usernum join
     user o
     on b.o_player = o.usernum
where 'Joe' in (x.usernam, o.usernam);
```

Comment: Hey gordon, your query executed, but unfortunately, it didn't show the names of Joe's opponents.

Comment: @Spartan117 . . . Could that be because the `in` clause used `usernum` rather than `usernam`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to user a subquery for this, first select all the oponents no matter if he/she is the o_player or the x_player, and the get the name from the user table

```
SELECT usernam, oponetID
(SELECT CASE
   WHEN o_player <> 1 then o_player
   WHEN x_player <> 1 then x_player
   ELSE NULL
END oponentID
FROM board
WHERE o_player = 1 or x_player= 1
) INNER JOIN user ON oponentID = usernum
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always a few ways to skin this cat - another tack you could take is a UNION of the two cases:

```
SELECT usernam
FROM user
WHERE usernum IN (
    SELECT o_player FROM board WHERE x_player = 1
    UNION
    SELECT x_player FROM board WHERE o_player = 1
);
```

Comment: Hey Cade, that got the ID's of the players who faced Joe. How would i go about getting their names, which are in the user table?

Comment: @Spartan117 you can use a join or use a set construct like I used.  Performance will usually be equivalent.

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thank you!